# How can I import an external slide in powerpoint with officer in R?

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

I want to copy the content of two slides from two pptx files into one pptx file using officer in R.

I thave started with the following code:

```
slide1 = read_pptx('1.pptx') 
slide2 = read_pptx('2.pptx') 
slide2_content = slide2 %>% slide_summary()
```

Now - how do I get all content from slide2 attached to slide1 and save it to a new file?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the same problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a 'backwards' work-around:

```
my_pres <- read_pptx(path = "one_slide.pptx") # The pptx can have any number of slides
my_pres <- add_slide(my_pres)
my_pres <- ph_with(my_pres, "Hello world", location = ph_location_type(type = "title"))
move_slide(my_pres, 1,length(my_pres))
print(my_pres, target = 'one_slide_appended.pptx')
```

but this limits to including slides from a single source